# Proving inequality using Chebyshev's inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I got in trouble with this:

> suppose that $X_1,\dotsc,X_n$ are independent random variables. Show that for any $a>0$, $P(\max|S_k|>3a) < 3\max P(|S_k|>a)$ where $S_k=X_1+\dotsb+X_k$.

I tried to solve it using Chebyshev's inequality, but nothing gains.
I've been try to solve this problem about 2 days, but I have no idea what the clue is!

Please give me some advice.

Comment: Please add details. Maxima with regard to what parameter? From where to where to those random variables map? Is there any information given about the measure?

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience. k ranges from 1 to n. And there is no additional information.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Let $a>0$, for $k=1,2,\ldots, n$ let's do $$A_{k}=\left\{\max_{1\leq j \leq k-1}|S_{j}|\leq 3a, |S_{k}|>3a \right\}$$
so, we can see that $$\left\{ \max_{1\leq j \leq k} |S_{j}|>3a\right\}=\bigcup_{k=1}^{n}A_{k}, \quad A_{i}\cap A_{j} =\emptyset $$
it's to say the sets $\{A_{k}\}_{k=1}^{n}$ are disjoint.
Then use Chebyshev's inequality.